# Flex imagerender based on datagrid value

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, arcgis

I have a datagrid with an location and a list of activities Birdwatching, Boating, Camping. The datagrid is populated based on either a simple yes or no if the activity is offered at that location. I want to replace the yes / no with a separate image for each activity. I created a imagerender and I'm able to get the image to change but only to the birdwatching image. My question is, how can I get it to loop through that datagrid and display image according to the value?

Thanks.

```
package widgets.Samples.CononGeocoder2
{
    import mx.containers.HBox;
    import mx.controls.Image;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.*;

    public class ImageRenderer extends HBox
    {
        private var imageReference:Image = null;
        private var imageReference2:Image = null;
        private var imageReference3:Image = null;
        private var lbl:Label = new Label();
        private var img:Image = new Image();
        private var img2:Image = new Image();
        private var img3:Image = new Image();

        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            //if(value != null && imageReference == null)
            {

                for each(data in value)
                {

                if(value.Birdwatching == "yes") {
                    img.source = "assets/images/Birdwatching.png";
                    addChild(img)
                    lbl.text = "(" + value.Birdwatching + ")";
                    img.toolTip = "Birdwatching";
                    imageReference = img;
                    setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                    setStyle("paddingLeft","5");
                }
                if(value.Boating == "yes"){
                    img2.source = "assets/images/Boating.png";
                    addChild(img2)
                    lbl.text = "(" + value.Boating + ")";
                    img2.toolTip = "Boating";
                    imageReference2 = img2;
                    setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                    setStyle("paddingLeft","5");
                }
                if(value.Camping == "yes"){
                    img3.source = "assets/images/Camping.png";
                    addChild(img3)
                    lbl.text = "(" + value.Camping + ")";
                    img3.toolTip = "Camping";
                    imageReference3 = img3;
                    setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                    setStyle("paddingLeft","5");
                }
                //Place

                }
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

THe most simple way is to do this in MXML. Something like this:

```
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Image source="assets/images/Birdwatching.png" visible="{data. Birdwatching == 'yes'}" includeInLayout="{data.Birdwatching == 'yes'}" toolTip="Birdwatching" />
    <mx:Image source="assets/images/Boating.png" visible="{data. Boating == 'yes'}" includeInLayout="{data.Boating == 'yes'}" toolTip="Boating" />
    <mx:Image source="assets/images/Camping.png" visible="{data. Camping == 'yes'}" includeInLayout="{data.Camping == 'yes'}" toolTip="Camping" />
    <mx:Label text="{'(' + (data.Birdwatching == 'yes') ? 'Birdwatching' : '' + (data.Boating == 'yes') ? 'Boating' : '' + (data. Camping == 'yes') ? 'Camping' : '' +  ')'}" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Note it is just a draft so you need to adjust it for yourself.

If you prefer to use ActionScript you should learn [Flex components lifecycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html) and override `updateDisplayList()` method for displaying and positioning of subcomponents.

Comment: I wouldn't do it like this personally. You're creating an image object for each activity even if it's unnecessary. This isn't very memory efficient. I would override the `set data` function to check the values of the data being passed in and then add the images to a container via actionscript.

Comment: As for me, it is much more efficient way for newbie than using some advanced techniques with ActionScript.

Comment: @Constantiner You're absolutely right, this is the easier solution and will work in his situation, that's why I didn't downvote your answer. I thought it was important to also point out the potential issues with this solution in case he wanted to look into the more advanced techniques as well. Isn't that how we help the newbies graduate from their newbie status? :)

Comment: That's why I mentioned Flex components lifecycle and `updateDisplayList()` :)

Comment: @Constantiner Ah, I missed that part at the bottom. Good points and +1. :)

Comment: I think I am going to take the hard road using Actionscript. The database contains about 40 activities, I want the code to be efficient b/c is used online. I am going to read up on Flex components life cycle's. If there is any other information you could point me in the direction of learning more about what I am trying to do that would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Before I answer your question, I want to point out a few items.  Item Renderers have the potential to be used a ton, so you need to be sure they are as lean as possible.  For example, you are creating 3 instances of the image component every time.  If you need more, you can create them as needed.  In addition, you might want to investigate using Canvas or UIComponent as the superclass if you plan on reusing this a lot.

Next, your 'for' loop isn't needed.  You aren't looping over the value object.  You simply need to check to see if the properties are set to the correct value.  Other than that, your example should work ok (although optimization would be a separate discussion.  If for some reason it still doesn't work, use the debugger to see what the values are for that given item.